# php nested quotes error

Tags: php, nested, quotes

I need your help to fix those quotes who are returning me errors like this :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Here is my code:

```
$HTML_footer.='<option value="general" '($sr && ! $cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'== 'Ventes']) ? "selected='selected'" : ''  '>general</option> ';
```

Comment: how did you know that the error is for this line?

Comment: @Akram - possibly because the line is invalid PHP

Comment: i know that the error is from this line because if have this :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\starter\2.0\web\_inc\php\web.php on line 855

Comment: You forgot the concatenation operator: the `.` or "dot" here: `general" '($sr ` <--, should be `al" '.($sr `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code

```
$value = "";
if($sr && ! $cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'== 'Ventes']){
$value = "selected='selected'";
}


$HTML_footer.="<option value='general' $value>general</option> ";
```

Comment: I think it's a typo, you added an extra ')'

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Edited the answer as your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING parser token error occurs due to an unexpected quote -- or lack thereof. First check the condition if satisfy then make it selected in this way:

```
 if ( $sr && (!$cf['form_ok']) && ($cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry' == 'Ventes'])) {
    $HTML_footer = "<option value='general' selected='selected'>general</option> ";
 }
```

I hope it will help!

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the dots between the various strings you're trying to join together. PHP uses a dot as the operator to join strings.

Also, the ternary operator needs to be enclosed in brackets to prevent it being ambiguous.

With those corrections, your line of code now looks like this:

```
$HTML_footer.='<option value="general" ' . (($sr && ! $cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'== 'Ventes']) ? "selected='selected'" : '') . '>general</option> ';
```

But a suggestion: Try moving the ternary operator out of the string into separate lines of code. It will be much more readable that way:

```
$isSelected = ($sr && ! $cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'== 'Ventes']);
$selected = $isSelected ? "selected='selected'" : '';
$HTML_footer.='<option value="general" '.$selected.'>general</option> ';
```

Still not brilliantly readable, but a lot better than it was.

Comment: I didn't down-vote (don't know why this was down-voted, either), but the ternary needn't be enclosed in brackets, especially not the way you are doing. `$foo = 'bar '. $bar === true ? '!' : '?'.'<br/>';` is perfectly valid: `[expression] ? [expression] : [expression]` is what the parser is looking for, these parts can be distinguished without the brackets

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - I've had a few 'drive-by downvotes' recently. Disappointing when people downvote but aren't willing to explain. Re the ambiguity, as far as I'm concerned there is an ambiguity with the `'>general</option>'` part at the end as to whether it's part of the main string or part of the ternary's false condition: `''.'>gen..'` is an expression, so is it all part of the ternary or not? But whether the parser that has a problem with that or not is to some extent irrelevant, because the code also needs to be readable for people working on it in the future. Readability=maintainability.